# How to create layout with two boxes left side and one box right side

Tags: css, html, jquery-ui

I'm looking for a way to create web page which contains two divs one below other in left side and one wider div in right side:

```
+--------------------+------------------------------------+
|                    |                                    |
|        img1        |                                    |
|                    |                                    |
+--------------------+              img2 centered         |
| logon or register  |                                    |
|       Search       |                                    |
|                    |                                    |
+--------------------+------------------------------------+
```

I tried code below but it renders  img1 and logon div in same line.

This is ASP.NET MVC4 shopping card master page which is installed in different sites.

Some customers want all those 3 boxes in same line as in code below.
If reasonable those two layouts should be swithed easily using  style override in master page or some other simple way.

How to implement this?
jquery ui and responsible-slides are is used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
.site-topbanner {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.rslides {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

    .rslides li {
        -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        display: none; /*width: 100%;*/
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

        .rslides li:first-child {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
        }

    .rslides img {
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        border: 0;
    }

</style>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div style="margin: 0">
      <div class="site-topbar">
          <div class='site-topbanner'>
            <a><img id='img1'  width="175px" height="60px"/></a>
          </div>

        <div class='site-topbanner'>
            <div>
              <a>Logon</a>
              or <a>Register</a>
            </div>
       <form ><input /><input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form> 
        </div>
        <ul class="rslides">
            <li>
              <a>

<img id='img2' width="375px" height="60px" />

</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

      </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post your HTML/CSS etc in a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<style>
.leftside{ float: left; width:175px; } /* you can use any other width you want*/
.rightside{ text-align: center; margin-left:175px } /* you may add 10px more to left margin to step off from left side*/
</style>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div style="margin: 0">
      <div class="leftside">
         <a><img id='img1'  width="175px" height="60px"/></a>
         <div>
           <a>Logon</a>
           or <a>Register</a>
           <form ><input /><input class="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Search" /> </form> 
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
        <li>
          <a>
           <img id='img2' width="375px" height="60px" />
          </a>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

the style you wrote:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

will not affect vertical placement of your image significantly - it's actual for objects of size comparable to text line height only. Thus it's good idea to deside about height of your  boxes and then write corresponding styles.

Another way is to use tables or elements with "display:table-cell" style

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I removed heights from styles since those may vary. Height of right side banner is greater than left side two boxes height. How to center left boxes vertically? I added `vertical-align: middle ` to `.leftside style`, but boxes still start immediately from uppler left cornet, not aligned.

Comment: Try add `display: table-cell` to `.leftside`. This will force left box behave like table cell, which can center vertically it's contents. Other display styles does not support vertical alignment of it's contents